# Trying to identify a string in a strcmp instruction

Tags: disassembly, binary-analysis, firmware, radare2, binary

Working to debug and analyze a piece of firmware, I've come across a bunch of cgi files which are all symlinked to a central cgi file. The first thing the main function does is run a series of string comparisons to identify which cgi file's functions should be run.

The issue is I am now trying to map the functions to their respective cgi names, but I am relatively new to binary debugging and cannot figure how to identify which values represent the string hard-coded into memory that the input is being compared to. I am using Radare2 and a sample of the code and a screenshot of the structure can be seen below.

Any advice would be appreciated!

```
0x000099a4   08001be5    ldr r0, [fp - local_8h]   ; const char * s1
0x000099a8   b81709e3    movw r1, 0x97b8
0x000099ac   021040e3    movt r1, 2                ; const char * s2
0x000099b0   5affffeb     bl sym.imp.strcmp        ;[3]; int strcmp(const char *s1, const char *s2)
0x000099b4   0030a0e1    mov r3, r0
0x000099b8   000053e3    cmp r3, 0
0x000099bc   0500001a    bne 0x99d8                ;[4]
0x000099c0   10001be5    ldr r0, [fp - local_10h]
0x000099c4   14101be5    ldr r1, [fp - local_14h]
0x000099c8   18201be5    ldr r2, [fp - local_18h]
0x000099cc   1f4e00eb    bl sub.setuid_250         ;[5]
0x000099d0   0c000be5    str r0, [fp - local_ch]
```

[image: Structure]

Comment: could you provide the output of the command `ag $$ > graph.dot` (you can plot it using `dot -Tpng graph.dot -o graph.png` if you got graphviz)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to read the ARM instruction reference. `movt` is the ["Move Top" instruction](http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/armasm/armasm_dom1361289879724.htm), which sets the top 16 bits of a register to the specified value without changing the low 16 bits.

In other words, the sequence:

```
movw r1, 0x97b8
movt r1, 2
```

is equivalent to:

```
r1 = 0x97b8
r1 |= (2<<16);
```

which results in  `r1= 0x297b8`, so that check that address for the string being compared to.